# Thumbnails and images in the blog post are not loading

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails

I have a blog that has many images in it. Recently I encountered an issue that the images in the blog posts do not load if I refresh it after a while. This is the same with the thumbnail as well. What would be the reason and the solution for it?

Comment: Does your HTML source still show the proper image `src`? Can you load those images in a new tab? Is your browser console showing any errors? Does the network tab in your browser dev tools showing any errors when it tries to load the images?

Comment: The most common reason for that is caching plugins. Try deactivating all of your plugins.